# Nextcord sending characteristics of a message rather than the content of it

Tags: python, bots, nextcord

I am using nextcord for a bot and need the bot to repeat a message in a different channel than what it was sent in. I am getting the data for the message rather than the message itself.

Here is my code:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.id
    check = message.author.id
    for x in pinged:
        print(x)
        print(check)
        if check == x:
            user = bot.get_channel(1128256630828568596)
            await user.send(message)
            await message.delete()
            break
```

I expected 'hi' to comeback if i wrote 'hi' but instead I received

```py
<Message id=1128878833827852298 channel=<TextChannel id=651164451860512792 name='general' position=4 nsfw=False news=False category_id=651164451860512788> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id=331289358235860992 name='---' discriminator='0' bot=False nick='---' guild=<Guild id=651164451386687504 name='---' shard_id=0 chunked=True member_count=119>> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `message` is [Message](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html#message) instance. To get the content of the message, use [Message.content](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html#nextcord.Message.content) (`message.content`) or [Message.system_content](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html#nextcord.Message.system_content) (`message.system_content`).